# iOS Firebase detach observer listener

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a UITabBarController that contains two tabs. Both of the are observing firebase data change.

The issue that I'm seeing is that when I do UITabBarController.dismiss, the listeners that are inside the two tabs are still alive. Does anyone knows if firebase removes the listeners when you do a dismiss? or should I remove the listeners manually? When I dismiss this UITabBarController I want to kill any viewController that are inside with their listeners.

I know that the suggestion is to add and remove the listeners on viewDidAppear and viewWillDissAppear, the main issue with that is that is a list of people and I don't want to be refreshing the list every time the user go to main page..

Does anyone else going through the same issue? On Android is easy because everything get destroy on onDestroy() method, but I'm new on iOS so I probably I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit.

If you attach a listener with [`observeSingleEvent(of:`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once), it will automatically be removed after the first results come back.

If you attach a listener with `observe`, it will only be removed when you [call `removeObserverWithHandle`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#detach_listeners).

Note that on Android `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to run, so you should never rely on it there either. Typically if you want your listeners to live longer than a single Activity/View, you should implement your own lifecycle management for them.

Comment: Yes, I'm using android view model with live data so I know the listeners are being detached. Do you know how can I add and remove the listeners without loading the list every time the view appear on iOS? It's really awful for the user

Comment: As said: you'll need to call `removeObserverWithHandle()` to remove the observer when it is no longer needed. Typically this will be in the inverse method of where you attach them.